# Content Security Policy - style-src - refuse to apply

Tags: .htaccess, security, content-security-policy

I wanted to create CSP for one of my sites.

I defined CSP in my .htaccess for scripts, styles, images, fonts but one thing always happens that I cannot understand.

```
"default-src 'none';script-src 'unsafe-inline' 'self' *.googleapis.com *.google-analytics.com;style-src 'unsafe-inline' 'self' *.bootstrapcdn.com *.googleapis.com; font-src 'self' fonts.gstatic.com *.bootstrapcdn.com; img-src 'self' *.googleapis.com"
```

This is my CSP and as you can see on the picture below (style-src **'unsafe-inline'** 'self' *.bootstrapcdn.com *.googleapis.com) this unsafe-inline option is ignored.

I just want to know why.

[image: CSP refuses to apply]

Thank you good people in advance :)

Comment: I can across the same problem and resolved it in this post. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37720467/content-security-policy-style-src-refuse-to-apply?rq=1)

Answer (score 1):

The CSP directive in the image does not match the one you've specified. Depending on how you are setting the CSP (response header or meta tag), you may need to restart your server that introduces the header or reload your page.